# More than one registerForContextMenu(View v) handling

Tags: android

I have 4*7 table and I want to handle every Edit text there , when the user clicks on the 5th edit text for long enough so that the menu pops up he can choose what color he wants.

the problem is how should I do this, I have 4*7 edittexts so I should call registerForContextMenu(View) 28 times even if I did this How can I handle it in onContextItemSelected(menuItem) ?

I don't want to put the whole fragment's view since everytime the user clicks for too long on any position the menu will pop up , so I don't want that.

Edit:

I tried this in the onCreateContextMenu:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.table_item1){

            Position = 1;

        }
```

and check for the position in the onContextItemSelected , is there a better way/ faster way than this ? since I'll need to put 28 if there :(

Comment: could you post your fragment class. you could make a function that would be flexible to handle 28 edit text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could name your `EditTexts` edit1, edit2, edit3 etc.
Then you could do a loop

```
for(int i=1; i<=28; ++i) {
   int resId = getResources.getIdentifier("edit" + i, "id", getPackageName());
   EditText edt = (EditText)findViewById(resId);
   edt.registerForContextMenu(...)
}
```

and the same in other places where you have to iterate over your `EditText`s